# Laplacian Boundary Value Problem

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Given a domain $ M \subset \mathbb{R}^2 $ and a function $ f : \partial M \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $, let $ \omega $ solve the boundary value problem:
$$
\Delta \omega = 0 \text{ in } M \\
\omega = f \text{ in } \partial M
$$
I would like to find some bounds on $ \omega, \partial_x \omega, \partial_x^2 \omega, \partial_y \omega, \partial_y^2 \omega $. Well, | $ \omega $ | is easy. But, is there anything I can say about the derivatives, in terms of $ f $?

If one considers the case where $ M $ is a square, then the usual fourier tricks are helpful. Is there something I can do for general regions $ M $?

Comment: What type of solution you are looking for? Weak?Strong?Classical?

Comment: Classical solution.

Comment: Schauder estimate in the PDE bible (Gilbarg-Trudinger) reads: $$\|\omega\|_{C^{2,\alpha}(M)}\leq C |f|_{C^{2,\alpha}(\partial M)}$$, where the first norm is the full norm for $C^{2,\alpha}$-functions (Holder continuous), second norm is the semi-norm on boundary.

Comment: There are also Calderon-Zygmund type $W^{2,p}$ estimates if you want those (also in Gilbarg Trudinger, Chapter 9 in this case. Schauder estimates are in Chapter 4 for the Laplacian).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in comments by Shucao Cao and Ray Yang, Gilbarg-Trudinger is the place  to look up such estimates: it does not have `3704` MathSciNet citations for nothing (as of today). In addition to global Hölder and Sobolev estimates (which require appropriate smoothness of $\partial  M$ and $f$) there is a  simple *interior* estimate for the Laplace equation, which applies in great generality. I quote it below.

**Theorem 2.10.** Let $u$ be harmonic in $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and let $\Omega'$ be a  compact subset of $\Omega$. Then for any multi-index $\alpha$ we have 
$$\sup_{\Omega'} |D^\alpha u|\le \left(\frac{n|\alpha|}{d}\right)^{|\alpha|}\sup_\Omega |u|$$ where $d=\operatorname{dist}(\Omega',\partial\Omega)$.

By the maximum principle, you can replace $\sup_\Omega |u|$ with $\sup_{\partial \Omega}|f|$ where $f$ is the boundary data.